# Sessions in JSP

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, jsp, servlets

I would like to know the corressponding Java code for the following ASP.net code. I have created a session....in this code I would like to use it in my servlets also.

```
        public static ShoppingCart Current
    {
        get
        {
            var cart = HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] as ShoppingCart;
            if (null == cart)
            {
                cart = new ShoppingCart();
                cart.Items = new List<CartItem>();

                if (mySession.Current._isCustomer==true)
                cart.Items = ShoppingCart.loadCart(mySession.Current._loginId);

                HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = cart;
            }
            return cart;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`HttpSession#setAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [`#getAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("cart");

if (cart == null) {
    cart = new ShoppingCart();
    session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
}

// ...
```

It's accessible in JSP EL by `${cart}` as well.

---

**Update** as per your comment, you can truly refactor it into a helper method in the `ShoppingCart` class:

```
public static ShoppingCart getInstance(HttpSession session) {
    ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("cart");

    if (cart == null) {
        cart = new ShoppingCart();
        session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
    }

    return cart;
}
```

and then use it as follows

```
ShoppingCart cart = ShoppingCart.getInstance(request.getSession());
// ...
```

Comment: Since i will be having many pages...i want the session to be created on any page...so do i have to copy this code to every servlet?

Comment: See answer update. You can however also go for a MVC framework instead.